# Omit links, ads, etc. from jsoup parse

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am using jsoup to scrape different html pages:

```
public class HtmlParse {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     String site = args[0];
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(site).get();
        String htm = doc.body().text();
        System.out.println(htm);
    }
}
```

It works beautifully. However, there seems to be a lot of fluff associated with its returns (ie: website links [a href]). Is there a quick way to omit this in jsoup? I found the [getElementsByTag](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByTag%28java.lang.String%29) literature but am having a hard time using it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can "clean" parsed Document, see [example](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer).
For exammple, to left only simple text:

```
Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.simpleText();
String result = Jsoup.clean(doc.html(), whitelist);
```

Or, you can simple delete all `a` tags:

```
doc.select("a").remove();
```

Comment: Whitelist still shows the text, however doc.select("a").remove();
does exactly what I was looking for, thank you!